# Sql Server - Selecting Logical Results in a Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

Suppose I have a table: `ACCOUNT`
It has columns: `ID`, `NAME`, `BALANCE`

I want to determine if the SUM of balances of people who has balance more than $ 2,000 is greater than $ 50,000.  It means I want to select a logical value. Because I don't want to get specific sum, I only need comparison result. I want to be able to write something like:

```
SELECT SUM(BALANCE) > 50000 
  FROM ACCOUNT
 WHERE BALANCE > 2000
```

Sql Server says it is syntax error. So I have to do:

```
SELECT SUM(BALANCE)  
  FROM ACCOUNT
 WHERE BALANCE > 2000
```

Then compare the result to 50000. **But taking sum of all the items after reaching 50000 is redundant since I only compare it to 50000.**

So how can I write this query in a way to stop after reaching comparison value and give me the logical result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was asked in 2011. In versions prior to 2012 there isn't really a clean way of doing this and getting SQL Server to short circuit the scan as soon as the total is reached.

You could use a recursive CTE to add up the balances instead. The exit condition for this could be once the balance running total exceeds 50,000. Dependant on table cardinality and indexes this could be either more or less efficient.

You could also have a custom CLR aggregate that terminated processing by throwing an error if 50,000 was reached but quite a horrible solution!

For versions since 2012 see [my answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/208183/3690)

Answer (score 2):

**You don't.**

How does `SQL Server` know you have only positive values?  If  you have 10 values, and the 8th one gets you over `50,000`, but 9 and 10 are both `-10,000`, wouldn't that be an issue?

Comment: Those are excluded by the over 2,000 condition

Comment: @MartinSmith - Logically they are, but depending on indexes they may not be filtered out before the `SUM` is run.

Comment: WHERE balance > 2000 provides it.

Comment: @JNK - That's irrelevant to this case as the `SUM` only includes values which are greater than 2,000. There is no **logical** reason why it would be impossible for it to short circuit and stop scanning once the target is reached.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I don't think there's a way to force the engine to do that short of using a `WHILE LOOP` or something.

Comment: Might be something that the extended `OVER` clause can help with, not sure. I can also think of an even more horrible solution than the CLR aggregate one using user variables but won't bother posting that one!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `HAVING` keyword.

```
SELECT sum(balance)
FROM account
WHERE balance > 2000
HAVING sum(balance) > 50000
```

*Edit:* This **likely** doesn't shortcut like the original question asked.  It *might* if the the SQL Server query engine realized the where/having clauses can be shortcut (as Martin Smith said in a comment).  I would think writing your own shortcut-er would be overly complicated, and if you're hitting performance issues there would likely be better approaches.

If you need a true/false answer via a query, then Jim Dagg's answer looks good to me.

Comment: @MartinSmith I was about to post the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, I was re-reading the question and thinking I missed the entirety of the question.  Working on an idea now....

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop the query unless you create a procedure with a cursor, which will stop fetching after reaching 50000 (don't know if it's worthing, but it's the only way, maybe you have millions of rows):

```
DECLARE @bal int
DECLARE @bal_tot int
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
SELECT sum(balance)
FROM account
WHERE balance > 2000
ORDER BY balance DESC;

OPEN cur;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur
INTO @bal
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 AND @bal_tot < 50000
BEGIN
@bal_tot = @bal_tot + @bal
END
CLOSE cur;

if @bal_tot > 50000 etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go the route of trying to write a complicated procedure to short-circuit the query.  -- that's overengineering the problem.  Honestly, just pulling the sum and doing the comparison the way you're doing now is the most straightforward method.
If you want to select the result of the comparison for use in other SQL processing, you could try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
    (SELECT SUM(AmtCurrent)
     FROM [SisMaster].[dbo].[Loan]
     WHERE AmtCurrent > 2000) > 50000 
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN  TotalAmtCurrent > 50000  THEN 1  ELSE 0  END 
FROM
    (SELECT SUM(AmtCurrent)  as TotalAmtCurrent    
    FROM [SisMaster].[dbo].[Loan]     
    WHERE AmtCurrent > 2000) a
```